# How do I use the 'Project Properties>Settings'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, save

I want to set a cache limit for my C# program so I decided to use the **Project Properties>Settings** function of Visual Studio [2015] to do so.

I had some help and was told to enter [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBzg.png).

***My settings I want are as follows:***

***Folder Path-*** C:\SysApp

***Size Limit-*** 150MB

***Amount to Delete-*** 149MB

For the `sizeLimit` and `toDelete` sections I need to know what unit (ie. bytes, megabytes, kilobytes...) they're in so I can convert them to what I listed above.

I was also told that

> If you change the settings value in the program you need to save the new values before exiting the application. This is done with `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`. This command creates a .config file with your values.

I need to know where in my coding to insert the `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` command.

Screenshots would be *very* helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no possibility to store metadata like units into default settings. You have to define the unit (kB, MB,...) the user should enter or store it as a string (e.g. 150MB) and parse it yourself.

The Save method must be called after setting the values (example):

```
Properties.Settings.Default.sizeLimit = 150000
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you only want to read the settings (see comments below) change the scope of the [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBzg.png) from "User" to "Application" and read the settings in your program like this:

```
class Program {
void main(string args[]) {

    String folderPath = Properties.Setings.Default.folder;
    int folderSizeLimit = Properties.Setings.Default.sizeLimit;
    int amountToDelete = Properties.Setings.Default.toDelete;
    DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(folderPath, folderSizeLimit, amountToDelete);
}
private private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string folderPath,
                                         long folderSizeLimit,
                                         long amountToDelete)
    ...... from other post .....
}
```

}

Comment: Yes and don't hesitate to upvote the answer, if it was useful.

Comment: So do I just paste that into Program.cs or Settings.cs or what?

Comment: Could you maybe possibly help me with a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand right. Do you want that the user could set them at runtime or do you make them only configurable (not hard coded)? In the first case you need a way, the user could enter this values (e.g. a form with text boxes), in the second case you don't need any code. Simpy go to the [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBzg.png) and change the scope from "User" to "Application". Then visual studio will create them in your application.config file and you can set them before starting the program.

Comment: [Here is my question from another forum if that helps.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/140m2hHyqYdF6uDlR4xarOGGqRnXZYHkpY0bsoQRDK6Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: But that question is a lead up from my [original question.](http://www.csharpforums.net/c-general-discussion/3249-cache-limit.html) Sorry this is so confusing...

Comment: With the link to the question from the other forum it is much clearer. Correct me if I am wrong but I assume: The is a program with write files to a cache folder. You want to write a "tool" to clean up the cache. If you want write a C# progrogrm for this, please see my editing answer above, but maybe a batch file or (powershell) script would be easier for this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't exactly know what a cache folder is. My program takes screenshots periodically of the computer it's installed on and saves them to a folder on that computer. It will then upload this screenshots periodically to a server of some sort (I'm still trying to figure this out). I want to add the function/command to the program for it to be able to periodically delete some of the screenshots from that folder so they don't use up too much space on the computer. Is this what you thought I meant?

Comment: I want it all to be one program if possible because it needs to be a stealth program that's completely hidden.

Comment: Does that make sense? Sorry for so many questions... I'm **really** grateful for your help. Thank you.